# Automate changing lua function arguments

Tags: python, lua

Hello first of all thank you for taking a look at this and I hope I'm not posting a question that has already been asked, I did look and I don't think I saw anything. So I have an lua script with maybe 400 lines of code or so that I need to change almost all of the arguments being passed to the functions. For example:

```
funcA(9, 306.5, 356.1);
pause(83225.46);
funcB(9, 302.5, 358.6);
pause(749948.79);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
funcA(9, 980.8, 642.0);
pause(83225.46);
funcB(9, 726.0, 646.5);
pause(749948.79);
```

So what I'm doing is taking the second and third arguments of some of the functions and converting them. Just hoping someone might be able to help me pull together a little python script that could automate this process.

Comment: What's the logic for the changes? How can you tell which functions need to get changed (and which don't)? Are there calls to those functions that *don't* need to be changed as well as calls that do?

Comment: There are only two or three functions in the whole script that need to be changed but they have many instances. Yes but they are all in the same order so that whether its funcA funcB or funcC they all need the second and third arguments changed. For a little more background all the arguments that need to be being passed to the function that need to be changed are coordinates. Those coordinates need to be adjusted to a different resolution.

Comment: Can't you just redefine `funcA` and `funcB` to do the conversion at run time?

Comment: No I don't have access to the source code of the application that actually runs the lua file.

Comment: You could define your own `funcA`, etc. in that file that wrap the original ones.

Comment: That's a good idea and I may do that but I have to modify many files so I would like to try to leave the files as clean as possible and do everything externally.